# Read array.xml from result array

Tags: java, android, arrays, xml, multidimensional-array

I'm having trouble with arrays.xml.

I want to read array from an array.

```
String[] arrKraje = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Slovakia);
String[] arrMesto = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.arrKraje[0]);
```

Can I make something like ↑?

If so, how?

Thanks.

I want to read from an array which is the result of another array `[string]`

---

```
<string-array name="Slovakia">
        <item>Bratislavský</item>
        <item>Trnavský</item>
        <item>Trenčiansky</item>
        <item>Nitriansky</item>
        <item>Žilinský</item>
        <item>Banskobystrický</item>
        <item>Prešovský</item>
        <item>Košický</item>
    </string-array>

    <string-array name="Bratislavský">
        <item>Bratislava I</item>
        <item>Bratislava II</item>
        <item>Bratislava III</item>
        <item>Bratislava IV</item>
        <item>Bratislava V</item>
        <item>Malacky</item>
        <item>Pezinok</item>
        <item>Senec</item>
    </string-array>
```

Comment: Paste your arrays.xml

Comment: you can achieve this type of array using hashmap or arraylist

Comment: it's array of constants. towns in region and region in country

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use getIdentifier method :

```
String[] arrKraje = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Slovakia);

int identifier = getResources().getIdentifier(arrKraje[0] , "array" , getPackageName());

String[] arrMesto = getResources().getStringArray(identifier);
```

Comment: what is pacagename?

Comment: *ok I use getActivity().getPacageName() but what it resault of thise code?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getPackageName()

Comment: getIdentifier return the identifier of your string array :
String[] arrMesto = getResources().getStringArray(getResources().getIdentifier(arrKraje[0] , "string" , getPackageName()));

Comment: I want use more arrays. 

first array it's for example class in school. I select index 0 for example 3.A 

And second array it's array with names of students in 3.A. 

I want read from array with names but i don't know from how class. when I select 1. index I want read from 3.A but when I select 2. index I want read from 4.B.

Comment: thise error 
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String array resource ID #0x0

in thise line String[] arrMesto = getResources().getStringArray(identifier);

my theory, identifier must be a string no? <string-array name="Bratislavský"> this string Bratislavský

Comment: try with getResources().getIdentifier(arrKraje[0], "array", getPackageName());

Comment: Works for me with "array"

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can,
You have to **referance to another array string.xml**

For example;

```
<string-array name="Slovakia">
  <item>@string/Bratislavský</item>
  <item>Bratislavský</item>
  <item>Trnavský</item>
  <item>Trenčiansky</item>
  <item>Nitriansky</item>
  <item>Žilinský</item>
  <item>Banskobystrický</item>
  <item>Prešovský</item>
  <item>Košický</item>
</string-array>

 <string-array name="Bratislavský">
    <item>Bratislava I</item>
    <item>Bratislava II</item>
    <item>Bratislava III</item>
    <item>Bratislava IV</item>
    <item>Bratislava V</item>
    <item>Malacky</item>
    <item>Pezinok</item>
    <item>Senec</item>
</string-array>
```

Java Code:

```
String[] arrMesto = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.    arrKraje[0]      );
```